# Where can I find the "Add Framework Support" option in IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1 CE?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, ide, intellij-idea-2018

I'm struggling with this: I'm trying to add Maven to an **already existing** project in IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1 CE, but when I right-click on the project node, there's no `Add Framework Support` option.
Where can I find it.

Comment: There is a similar report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-188036,  but no requested information was provided by the user. Feel free to comment there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem in IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.2 (Community Edition). The fix is to delete the `.idea` and `.iml` files in your project root, then restart IntelliJ. Then the menu option should appear.